# Endless loop in python class member function. Threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, function, class

I need to implement something like this

```
def turnOn(self):
    self.isTurnedOn = True
    while self.isTurnedOn:
        updateThread = threading.Thread(target=self.updateNeighborsList, args=())
        updateThread.daemon = True
        updateThread.start()
        time.sleep(1)
def updateNeighborsList(self):
    self.neighbors=[]
    for candidate in points:
        distance = math.sqrt((candidate.X-self.X)**2 + (candidate.Y-self.Y)**2)
        if distance <= maxDistance and candidate!=self and candidate.isTurnedOn:
            self.neighbors.append(candidate)
    print self.neighbors
    print points
```

This is a class member function from which `updateNeighborsList` function should be called every second until `self.isTurnedOn == True`.
When I create class object and call `turnOn` function, all following statements are not being executed, it takes the control and stacks on that while loop, but I need a lot of objects of class.
What is the correct way to do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be better off creating a single `Thread` when `turnOn` is called, and have the looping happen inside that thread:

```
def turnOn(self):
    self.isTurnedOn = True
    self.updateThread = threading.Thread(target=self.updateNeighborsList, args=())
    self.updateThread.daemon = True
    self.updateThread.start()

def updateNeighborsList(self):
    while self.isTurnedOn:
        self.neighbors=[]
        for candidate in points:
            distance = math.sqrt((candidate.X-self.X)**2 + (candidate.Y-self.Y)**2)
            if distance <= maxDistance and candidate!=self and candidate.isTurnedOn:
                self.neighbors.append(candidate)
        print self.neighbors
        print points
        time.sleep(1)
```

Note, though, that doing mathematical calculations inside of a thread will not improve performance at all using CPython, because of the Global Interpreter Lock. In order to utilize multiple cores in parallel, you'll need to use the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html) module instead. However, if you're just trying to prevent your main thread from blocking, feel free to stick with threads. Just know that only one thread will ever actually be running at a time.

Comment: can you show an example, I am new in programming, thanks

Comment: @EdikMkoyan An example of what?

Comment: this is not clear for me
I think you'd be better off creating a single Thread when turnOn is called, and have the looping happen inside that thread:

Comment: @EdikMkoyan The code I put in my answer is an example demonstrating that. `turnOn` creates a single thread, which execuse `updateNeighborsList`. `updateNeighborsList` runs a while loop that will keep executing as long as `self.isTurnedOn == True`. Let me know if anything in the example isn't clear.

Comment: `updateNeighborsList` will keep running as long as `self.isTurnedOn` is `True`. If you're seeing different behavior, you'll need to edit your original question with enough code for me to reproduce exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: self.isTurnedOn is True all the time, I've even replaced it with True, but no use, only on object is being created after this


one = Point(10,20)
one.turnOn()
two = Point(11,20)
two.turnOn

Comment: Do you mean `two.turnOn()`? `two.turnOn` won't actually execute the `turnOn` method. And again, I really can't help you more unless you add enough code to your question for me to reproduce what you're doing.